# Can I set the background color of the ABAP editor?

Tags: text-editor, abap

Is there a chance to set the background color of the abap editor? Maybe to a dark color?

Comment: You can use the sap-standard ui-themes, If You want, 
But as sap-gui is a window, You can flag Your question with "winapi". And write "excuse" before the question. 
Winapi would involve MAXIMAL hooking techniques  into sap-gui-window-creation, determin the editor-window-id, hook its creation and  perhaps perhaps, with try and error, You can hook into  WM_CREATE and/ or WM_PAINT of the corresponding window and set BG_BRUSH to some color You want.
This hint is only hypothetical. And by the way, it more and more sounds like a nice chellange,WinSpy is the first step for this. A try ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SAP GUI 7.30 I click the option at the right bottom of the screen editor:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [It's in the online documentation](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_banking70/helpdata/en/43/2e5f8e572b3fece10000000a11466f/content.htm?frameset=/en/43/2d7964419b3fe1e10000000a11466f/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/ac/b6c5403b710366e10000000a1550b0/plain.htm&node_id=27)...

Comment: THANX. NEVER SEEN THIS BEFORE ( OR NEVER NOTICED).